# Build angular plotlyjs project using codebuild in AWS

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, plotly.js

I'm struggling to implement code pipeline for ci/cd specifically for my project in AWS. I keep having an error about plotlyjs which is actually a dependency i'm using in my application. After executing the ng build command the code build fails and sends an error regarding angular plotlyjs. Please i need help to proceed with my ci/cd.

Here is my buidspec.yml file

```
version: 0.2

env:
variables:
    CACHE_CONTROL: "86400"
    BUILD_FOLDER: "dist"
phases:
 install:
   runtime-versions:
    nodejs: 16
    commands:
    - echo Installing source NPM dependencies...
    - npm install
    - npm install -g @angular/cli
  build:
    commands:
    - echo Build started 
    - ng build
   artifacts:
   files:
    - '**/*'
base-directory: 'dist*'
discard-paths: yes
```

[image: error from codebuild]

Comment: I'm no aws expert, but in the linux world, exit code 137 often indicates an out of memory error, so this probably has nothing to do with plotly. Ng build needs a lot of memory.

Comment: Okay, Thank you. How can i increase the memory in codebuild aws.